# dnsmasq as dhcp server configuration for Ethernet

Tags: centos, ethernet, dnsmasq

I'm trying to configure **dnsmasq** as dhcp server on CentOS 7 minimal installation.

My network consists of wi-fi AP, Ethernet, Bluetooth PAN and bridge called **common-bridge**  which serves as master for all of them.
dnsmasq is listening on **common-bridge** interface with following config:

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
no-resolv
filterwin2k
expand-hosts
listen-address=127.0.0.1
listen-address=192.168.1.1
dhcp-range=192.168.1.5,192.168.1.150
```

The strange thing is that DHCP is working fine with Wi-Fi and BT, but Ethernet client can't obtain IP address.

Looks like there is no traffic at all because **tcpdump** shows no traffic on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related unstable network card driver (**r8169**) and is not related to network configuration.

Steps to install stable driver are described in Hetzner tutorial ([link](https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/installing-the-r8168-driver))